# Login to Subscriber Org doesn't work

Tags: subscriber, lma, support, grant-login-access, salesforce-support

Even though I have granted login access in Subscriber org to my LMO, I can't login in LMO to the Subscriber Org.
[image]

What may be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have opened Salesforce Support Case and during my call with Salesforce Support, we have figured out that this wasn't working since I had LMA installed in Developer Edition org. When I requested for PBO and used LMA there, this option has appeared.

Documentation says that Log In to Subscriber Orgs feature works only in [Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited
Editions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lma_logging_in_to_sub_org.htm&type=5) orgs.